# Create a "visual noise matrix" in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mask, noise

In order to avoid "retinal persistence" after the presentation of a stimuli, I need to create a visual noise mask.

[image]

This for a screen that has a dimension, in pixel of : 1280 * 960

I believe I could randomly (uniform) assign gray shade to pixels but my attempts yet failed.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you also need the black frame?

Comment: @Brett, no thank you very much, it was to ease the viewing :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try looking in the help docs?  One of the first examples for [Image](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image.html) should have done it.

```
Image@RandomReal[1, {960, 1280}]
```

You can specify a different range of values:

```
Image@RandomReal[{0.4, 1}, {400, 600}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow :-) I did not. This is perfect. Thank You !

Comment: @500 I am still glad to help, and an easy question like this takes but a few minutes, but I am concerned that you could not find this for yourself.  Do you have trouble navigating the documentation? (You'd not be alone.)

Comment: To me the problem is that the help is great once you know the function you need to use. But for exploring/discovery mode, I find it very hard...

Comment: @500, that is my general complaint with it, also. The v.5, and earlier, help system was much better in that regard.

Comment: @rcollyer Do you mean `FrontEndTokenExecute["HelpDialog"]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no. The documentation center in v.6, and higher, is completely different than the prior versions, and it's layout makes finding "new" (to you at least) functions difficult. In prior versions, it was hierarchical, so that you could skim through everything within one branch of the hierarchy and learn about it. That's how I picked up on the functional aspects of mma.

Comment: @rcollyer Neither the Function Navigator nor the Virtual Book work for this?  Pardon me, it's been a long time since I used version 5.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have actually used neither of those. Maybe I need to educate myself on their utility before I make off-hand comments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, they look interesting, and may function in that capacity very well. I guess I got used to the "function navigator" functionality being built into the documentation center.

Comment: @500 There were lots of complaints when the v6 help system was introduced.  As you say, individual pages are good, but there was no proper table of contents, or no way to remember *where* a certain page was found.  The virtual book was introduced as a response to these concern.  Try the virtual book button!  (Not as good as the v5 navigator, and doesn't have links to *everything*, but still pretty useful.)

Comment: One really needs to read tutorials and how to's. When burrowing through a problem I used to zoom past them, convinced I would find what I needed faster. For instance, having scoured the image processing guide with telescopic vision, I implemented my own color separation functions. It seemed very strange that they weren't there. A couple days later I happened to notice Color Processing. I would appreciate guides of guides, not content pages, rather a graph of guides (nodes) where many "subject paths" lead you to the guides you most likely need.

Answer (score 8):

Just noticed:

```
RandomImage[1, {1280, 960}]
```

New in Mathematica 8, apparently...

Comment: Well shucks, I can't beat that! :-)

Comment: @Mr.wizard Yes, you can! 1~RandomImage~{1280, 960} It's 1 character shorter.  (I really hate myself for perpetuating this stale joke, but I simply couldn't resist)

Answer (score 5):

Damn, at last a question on Stack Overflow I could have answered and I was too late... :)

Oh well, here's an alternative solution...

```
ImageEffect[Image[Table[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {i, 1, 960}, {j, 1, 1280}] ], "GaussianNoise"]
```

[image: noisy]

Probably got too many colours in it?

`ImageEffect` also works on greyscale images.

```
ImageEffect[Image[Table[0.5, {400}, {600}]], "GaussianNoise"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You're not too late; that is a very different method.  You could use `ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"]` to discard the colors.

Comment: I made an edit, hopefully in the spirit of your method, which I like.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already shown you ways of creating a random image. In case you were designing your application to use up the full screen (or based on the current screen's dimensions), you might find it convenient to not hard code the values, but to capture the screen size programmatically. Here's an example showing how:

```
screenSize = Last /@ ("FullScreenArea" /. 
   Flatten@SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]);
RandomImage[1, screenSize]
```